# how to do this in groovy, range from 1 and greater

Tags: groovy, range

I want numbers from 1 and greater
I tried 1..n, but this doesn't work
So I can't do this in Range?

thanks

Comment: You want a continuous range from 1 to infinity?

Answer (score 3):

```
1..Integer.MAX_VALUE
or 
1..Long.MAX_VALUE
```

What do you want **n** to signify ?

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
def n = 3
def range = 1..n
range.each { println it }
```

Output:

```
$ groovy range.groovy 
1
2
3
```

Can you provide a script that isn't behaving as you would like?

Comment: `def n = -3`
`def range = 1..n`
`range.each { println it }`
if n < 1 then output is only `1`